# independence of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

For what values of $c$ are the vectors $U_0=[1,0,-1]$ , $U_1=[2,1,2]$ , $U_2=[1,1,c]$ linearly independent. I let the matrix $A$ composed of the three given vectors be augmented with the zero vector. I then row reduced and arrived at the conclusion that they will be linearly independent when $c$ is not equal to 1. Is this correct?

Comment: You could try proving for which value of c the vectors are linearly dependent instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right idea, but wrong answer.  Row reducing the matrix whose columns are given by the vectors should leave you with
$$
\pmatrix{1&0&-1&|&0\\0&1&1&|&0\\0&0&c-3&|&0}
$$

Answer (score 0):

The first two entries in all the vectors give you an invertible linear system so you can solve for the linear combination of vectors of first 2 entries in $U_0,U_1$ that gives you the first 2 entries in $U_2$. Let $V_0,V_1,V_2$ be the vectors of the first two entries. Then you get $V_1 - V_0 = V_2$. So the coefficients are $-1$ and $1$ to get linear dependence. This means the last entry in $U_2$ has to be $2 - (-1) = 3$ in order to get linear dependence. So any value $c \neq 3$ will give you linear independence.